# Using the Arduino compiler, is it possible to use Atmega2560 interrupt pins that are unused by Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, atmega2560, pcb-design

Looking into [the schematics for the Arduino Mega](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf) I noticed that pins PE6 and PE7 are interrupt-enabled (INT6 and INT7 respectively); however, they remain unconnected to any Arduino I/O pin.

I'm designing a custom board based on the Atmega2560 and want to use the Arduino IDE/Compiler to upload my code to it, so I'm pretty much replicating a big part of the Arduino Mega schematic into my board.

However, I would really like to enable these two extra interrupt pins (having 8 interrupt pins in total) in my board, but I'm now sure how to proceed from the software side. How could I enable this new pins in order to use them from the Arduino compiler?

[image: Atmega2560 Interrupt pins]

Thanks!

Comment: In the original Arduino Mega board variant the unconnected pins aren't defined in it. Just use [MegaCore](https://github.com/MCUdude/MegaCore) which defines all pins.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know this existed. I'll check it out, so far looks promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not afraid of getting your hands dirty by touching hardware
registers, you can access those pins bare-metal style, using [port
manipulation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation). You will have to read the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf),
specifically the section “External Interrupts” if that's what you are
after.

This works with the stock Arduino core (or even without core), which may
be interesting from a maintenance point of view, but it's not as easy to
use as the Arduino interrupt API.